# Solve nonlinear equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations

Suppose that $f:E\to F$(between Banach spaces), is of the form 
$$f(x)=f(0)+D(x)+N(x).$$
Here $D$ is a linear term, whose kernel is of finite dimension, and admits a right inverse $G$, i.e. $D(G)(\cdot)=Id_F$. The nonlinear term $N(x)$ satisfies that 
$$\|G(N(x))-G(N(y))\|\leq C(\|x\|+\|y\|)\|x-y\|$$

for some constant $C>0$ and $x,y$ in a small neighborhood $B_{\epsilon(C)}(0)$.

**Q**: How to show that there is a unique zero point $x_0$ of $f$, i.e. $f(x_0)=0$,  in $B_\epsilon(0)\cap G(F)$, with the initial condition $\|G(f(0))\|\leq\epsilon/2$?

This question comes from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2873492/355583

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the right and left inverses $D$ and $G$ are bounded linear operators, and that $$2C\epsilon<1.$$ Note that the range of $G$ is a closed linear complement to $\ker D$.

Your problem is then equivalent to the fixed point equation

$$\begin{cases} x=-GN(x)-Gf(0)  \\ x\in   \overline{B_\epsilon(0)}\cap  G(F) \ .\end{cases}$$

(Apply either $D$ or $G$ to pass from one equation to the other). For $\|x\|\le\epsilon $, since $GN(0)=0$, one has $\|-GN(x)-Gf(0) \|=\|GN(0)-GN(x) -Gf(0) \|\le C\epsilon^2+\epsilon/2\le\epsilon$, so that the map $x\mapsto -GN(x)-Gf(0) $ takes the closed set $\overline{B_\epsilon(0)}\cap  G(F)$ into itself. It is a contraction by the assumptions, and the conclusion follows from the contraction principle.